# Check if group contains same value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I am curious if there is a pre-built function in Pandas to check if all members of a group (factors in a column) contain the same value in another column.

i.e. if my dataframe was similar to below it would return an empty list.

```
Col1    Col2
2        A
2        A
0        B
0        B
```

However, if my dataframe appeared as such (**notice the 1 in Col1**):

```
Col1    Col2
2        A
2        A
0        B
1        B
```

Then the output would be a list containing the object "B" since the group B has different values in Col1.

Comment: Maybe something like `df.groupby('Col2')['Col1'].apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist())` ?

Comment: @jpp how about `df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)`  here??

Comment: @anky_91, Yeh that works too. Really depends on the precise output OP requires.

Comment: @jpp Agreed. :)

Comment: Interesting! These are both solutions I can work with. Thanks @anky_91 and jpp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use groupby nunique and index of unique values > 1

```
a = df.groupby('Col2').Col1.nunique() > 1
a[a].index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
['B']
```

Comment: Can someone explain why a[a] returns only entries where the condition resolved to True?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for boolean mask and convert column `Col2` to `list`:

```
a = df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep=False), 'Col2'].unique().tolist()
print (a)
[]
```

And for second data:

```
a = df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep=False), 'Col2'].unique().tolist()
print (a)
['B']
```

Alternative with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
a = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)['Col2'].unique().tolist()
print (a)
['B']
```